# How to add observations on "tidy" data and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in ["tidy"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjg4aOn8q7qAhVBolwKHfysAeoQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvita.had.co.nz%2Fpapers%2Ftidy-data.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3HDG0hKNeQpAOVcdczJizw) format (columns are variables, rows are observations).

but now I would like to add data to this DataFrame using pandas but I have a hard time working with this format of data.

Here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["John", "Physics", 78],
     ["Alice", "Physics", 58],
     ["Rachel", "Physics", 22],
     ["Tom", "Physics", 78],
     ["John", "Chemistry", 79],
     ["Alice", "Chemistry", 72],
     ["Rachel", "Chemistry", 61],
     ["Tom", "Chemistry", 89],
     ["John", "English", 56],
     ["Alice", "English", 91],
     ["Rachel", "English", 88],
     ["Tom", "English", 56],
     ["John", "Math", 95],
     ["Alice", "Math", 81],
     ["Rachel", "Math", 64],
     ["Tom", "Math", 83]],
    columns=["name", "measure", "value"])
print(df)
```

Here is an overview:

```
      name    measure  value
0     John    Physics     78
1    Alice    Physics     58
2   Rachel    Physics     22
3      Tom    Physics     78
4     John  Chemistry     79
5    Alice  Chemistry     72
6   Rachel  Chemistry     61
7      Tom  Chemistry     89
8     John    English     56
9    Alice    English     91
10  Rachel    English     88
11     Tom    English     56
12    John       Math     95
13   Alice       Math     81
14  Rachel       Math     64
15     Tom       Math     83
```

What I want to do is, for example, add the mean value of scientific notations for each student, and keep the tidy format.

In raw format, it will be simple, and will looks like this and one line is enough:

```
df.Sciences = (df.Physics + df.Chemistry + df.Math)/3
```

But how on tidy ? What is the most efficient way?
Please use a lambda function because, in my real data, the work to do on data is more complicated than just a mean value.

I expect that:

```
    name    measure     value
0   John    Physics     78
1   Alice   Physics     58
2   Rachel  Physics     22
3   Tom     Physics     78
4   John    Chemistry   79
5   Alice   Chemistry   72
6   Rachel  Chemistry   61
7   Tom     Chemistry   89
8   John    English     56
9   Alice   English     91
10  Rachel  English     88
11  Tom     English     56
12  John    Math        95
13  Alice   Math        81
14  Rachel  Math        64
15  Tom     Math        83
16  John    Sciences    84
17  Alice   Sciences    70.33333333
18  Rachel  Sciences    49
19  Tom     Sciences    83.33333333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply `pivot` it:

```
new = df.pivot("name","measure","value")

new["Science"] = (new["Chemistry"] + new["Math"] + new["Physics"])/3

print (new)

measure  Chemistry  English  Math  Physics    Science
name                                                 
Alice           72       91    81       58  70.333333
John            79       56    95       78  84.000000
Rachel          61       88    64       22  49.000000
Tom             89       56    83       78  83.333333
```

UPDATED: If you insist on long form:

```
s = (df.loc[df["measure"].ne("English")]
       .groupby("name").apply(lambda d: d["value"].mean())
       .reset_index(name="value")
       .assign(measure="Science"))

print (pd.concat([df,s],sort=False, ignore_index=True))

      name    measure      value
0     John    Physics  78.000000
1    Alice    Physics  58.000000
2   Rachel    Physics  22.000000
3      Tom    Physics  78.000000
4     John  Chemistry  79.000000
5    Alice  Chemistry  72.000000
6   Rachel  Chemistry  61.000000
7      Tom  Chemistry  89.000000
8     John    English  56.000000
9    Alice    English  91.000000
10  Rachel    English  88.000000
11     Tom    English  56.000000
12    John       Math  95.000000
13   Alice       Math  81.000000
14  Rachel       Math  64.000000
15     Tom       Math  83.000000
16   Alice    Science  70.333333
17    John    Science  84.000000
18  Rachel    Science  49.000000
19     Tom    Science  83.333333
```

Comment: We still do not have a tidy format as a result. So should we use a melt then ?

Comment: I don't see the benefits of keeping it as long form, but i have updated my answer to include it @Samovian.

Comment: Thanks you ! I agree with you that the long format is not that easy to work with.